# Explaining observations/concepts/conclusions to people who are unaware of your Domain Knowledge

Tags: professionalism, team, knowledge-transfer

I am software developer. During last five years I have tried to grab knowledge from various technical areas and from colleagues. And now I landed up in a company where the people in my team are either have only manager role/ scrum master, QA's,  BA's' and developers with only a few years of experience.  But in technical discussions, all of them have a say about implementation, bandwidths, timelines, even though they are unaware of what the path is going to be for development of certain features.

Now the thing is whenever some issue comes up in our project, I can hear the other developers in the team/ members discussing the various reasons that why that may have happened, passing their own judgement. However at that point in time I listen to them silently because I have seen people getting offended when you try to correct them. However when the dust settles, I do add my opinion to the discussion.

The actual problem lies in the fact when you provide them with a solution, then the people with the knowledge gained from the little Google search start challenging your knowledge and suggest that we should go with the other solution without understanding the problem completely. As a result one more task gets added in my list, to explain the pros and cons of the other approach.

**Now My Question is how to handle such challenges, the challenges which are raised by people in your team having no knowledge of your domain and still you have to politely explain to them why the approach you suggest is the best/better then the approach they suggests, (even though they are unaware of the domain.)**

Should I be answerable? 
Or Should I take part in the conversations?
Or just let them discuss, and let them maintain the essence that they know it better.

Comment: If you have the domain knowledge, then why can't you simply explain why your approach is better?

Comment: @sf02 because some you have to work with are “all mouth and no trousers”...

Comment: @SolarMike These are team members on the project, so if OP is going to reject their suggestions he should be capable of explaining why.  I think correcting these colleagues would be less offensive than simply ignoring their suggestions.

Comment: @sf02 because I know upfront that they know nothing about the stuff they are asking and they are either gonna get convinced or will just delay the final decision a few days which even then will be the same solution as suggested by the expert before.

Comment: @sf02 for reference , [see this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKorP55Aqvg)

Comment: @sf02 in the above reference, they all are team members

Comment: You say you mention 5 years experience, while your team mates have "only a few years of experience" does that really make you more experienced than your colleagues? Do they see you as more experienced?

Comment: @Helena well I am not the one with the supreme intelligence :D, But the other developers are having either 3 or 4 years of experience and that too in backend, while I am a full stack developer. And we sort of consider each and everyone's opinion, so everybody have their say in the decisions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I too am a software developer.

The answerers telling you that "if you're actually a domain expert you should be able to explain it" and quoting Einstein are not actually answering your question. The situation you find yourself in is extremely common.

I am fortunate enough to have a ratio of software developers to management of 5:1. The managers have been wrong enough times that they now know that they can trust the devs. Not everyone is so fortunate.

1. Work on your communication skills. I have found as time has gone on that the more metaphors I use the better people understand me. I have actually learned a lot about communicating to a wide audience by studying the parables of Jesus. I prefer talking to computers over people. This was the biggest adjustment I had to make in my professional life.
2. Do not wait until the end of the meeting to contribute to the conversation. Many people who become decision-makers become that because they BS their way through things in a confident manner. Not contributing to a conversation because you're waiting for all the hot air to dissipate may be read by these people as a form of acquiescence. Having a game plan for the meeting before you go in so you can cast your vision early will go a long way to shortening the meetings and getting the blowhards to trust you.
3. Do not communicate condescendingly. You want them to trust you, not to feel stupid. Be positive and enthusiastic about your solution.
4. Learn what the decision makers care about. Some times it is time. If you explain in an understandable way (see point 1) why solution A will take 3 weeks and solution B will take 10 weeks, you will probably convince the decision-maker to go with your solution. UNLESS that decision-maker doesn't care about timelines. Find out what the decision-makers value and sell your solution along those lines. Saying, "The framework you're suggesting is out of date" won't matter to a decision-maker concerned primarily with timeline. It may have more sway on a decision-maker tormented by security vulnerabilities.
5. Talk with a decision-maker directly beside or above you about your solution and why it is better before the meeting. They will advocate for you in the meeting, sometimes without knowing why. They simply feel smarter because you've gotten them on the inside of the better solution before the meeting. And these people love nothing more than feeling smarter than everyone else in the room. Give them that warm fuzzy feeling.
6. Make sure your solution is actually the best solution. Don't become one of these people who wants it your way. Genuinely want it the best way. If you don't, all of this is a waste of time.

As far as not offering to implement their solution....
In some places that will get you fired. At the least it will make you unpopular. In my company you will be reassigned to a miserable job and kept there until you quit. My philosophy about work is to do your best work, even if you know it isn't your idea. Even if you know your idea is better. Do not intentionally delay your implementation of their solution.

The long term goal is to educate the decision-makers about the domain. If you focus on this goal rather than on the short-term goal of having your way, you will eventually end up with the trust of the decision-makers. And that generally leads to a better workplace experience, compensation, etc. Your situation is frustrating. I have been there. During that time it can be easy to see it as a me vs. them problem. Viewing it as a team problem is the right way to view it.

Answer (score 19):

When I was a beginner many years ago, there was a situation when I understood something, the PM understood it, but the rest of the team did not. My explanations were not very useful. The discussions only closed temporarily until they opened again on the same topic.

I was initially confused by the approach of the PM, but I eventually understood it and adopted it. It was very helpful throughout the years.

The Method

Do not explain.

Let them present a solution. Then ask a question. Let them answer. Ask them another question. Let them answer. Continue until they understand that their solution is flawed.

Repeat until no more flawed solutions exist.

If a good solution is found, adopt it. If no other solution can be generated by the team, suggest a solution. Receive questions. Provide answers.

In the end, everybody will have to be happy - even if some egos might get hurt a little.

---

Clarification: All the procedure above happens during EXACTLY one meeting, not trial and error throughout the life of the project.

Worst case: a follow up meeting may be necessary, if something needs to be actually tested in the real world.

---

Gradually, they will come to understand that you understand things better and faster, and they will eventually come to trust you and let you talk first - what you actually want.

Comment: repeat, repeat, repeat... that can happen very late and can be very damaging from many points of view, to very many people. I strongly disagree.

Comment: You obviously mock me (no offense taken), but I have no idea what you want to say.

Comment: I make the point that you have to repeat the process, as many times as necessary, which wastes your time and their time - my answer lets them waste their time but not yours, well mine...

Comment: Aha, now I get it. You are right, we talk here about the education - which is never instant. But "my way" will not jeopardize the project, because fresh graduates took the wrong strategical decisions.

Comment: "which wastes your time and their time" - actually I see it as **invested** time, rather than _wasted_ - invested in their education. In this way, you become a coach, a knowledge leader, and they have a chance to learn things the correct way, without actually reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You also assume that there is enough time for your iterative process... What happens when there is not...

Comment: Well, there are situations and situations. Of course, if the house is on fire, there is no time for education. Just throw out everything that needs to be saved. But usually, things are not really that "black". I do not expect these kinds of discussion to be needed twice every day.

Comment: I was involved on working on a boiler. The others wanted to do process X, I did not. I explained my reasoning and they just did not see it my way. So, I said "fine, you can follow your plan, just give me 5 minutes to get to the car park". They said "are you serious?" I said well I warned you that with your plan the boiler could explode... They went with my plan.

Comment: Your situation is not related to under-education or stubbornness, is just that some more-or-less reasonable people did not understand a potential risk. Once the detail was explained (technically or metaphorically, even jokingly), they agreed with you and went your way.That is normal every-day business.

Comment: I like this answer because it encourages the other employees to feel like they invented the solution themselves.... and thus improves buy in on their part.

Comment: It looks like OP is suffering from a mix of Not Invented Here and Dunning-Kruger, I think this answer is the most effective one in the long run for deconstructing that

Comment: FWIW: That ask questions until they realize their own problem is "The Socratic Method" - https://www.wikihow.com/Argue-Using-the-Socratic-Method

Comment: @WesleyLong: I did not know that. Thanks ;)

Comment: I think this is definitely one of the better ways to address this issue, if it works. The problem I've run into is that some people are just unreasonable. For example, most of my more aggravating experiences around this are people who question the value of abstraction layers. The approach you lay out is problematic here because the abstraction layer solves for a problem that doesn't exist (yet) and we can't get past the YAGNI arguments regardless of how many times that particular solution has been re-engineered. If you get to that point, you may have to push the amateurs out of the discussion.

Comment: "you may have to push the amateurs" - totally right - unless the management is in the boat with them, and they push back. Been there, done that :( The only thing I could do in that situation was to watch helpless. And then leave, when the opportunity came.

Answer (score 15):

You make your suggestion and if they don’t accept it then let them choose their own.

But don’t offer to do their solution...

If they then come back to you as it has failed or struggled, re-offer your solution. Worked for me in several spheres but don’t offer to repair their solution : that way madness lies...

Comment: I think this is the right approach. As they say in the boy scouts: learning by doing. Just a warning though: some people will not get it anyway...

Comment: Well this is the most practical thing I can do, however I am still worried for the explanations which I have to give at later stage for the failure of their decisions

Comment: @nobalG sometimes  I find the explanations take longer than just doing the task...

Comment: "If they then come back to you as it has failed or struggled" - that can happen very late and **can be very damaging** from many points of view, to very many people. I strongly disagree.

Comment: @virolino From the business perspective in that one case sure. However, this employee needs to gain the ability to either trust his manager, or learn how the manager came to the conclusion. Either way, by fixing his mistake, he learns nothing and will simply repeat it. If the manager knows this alternate fix isn't going to work, he can easily have someone work on the real solution in parallel while this one guy does his own thing. A business, by its very nature, is always about risk. If a company does everything with no risk, they die.

Comment: @Nelson: The discussion is not about managers, neither the question, nor the answers. It is about employees, with vs. without experience.

Comment: @virolino Sorry about that.  The comment about "can be very damaging from many points of view, to very many people" is usually a management level or higher concern. I simply cannot be responsible for someone at the same level as myself without causing unhealthy tension with my co-workers. I'll probably just remind them that they will be responsible for the decision.

Comment: @Nelson: if I am going to get hurt, I do not care if that is a concern of the management or not. I will have to deal with it. And if I can do it without creating tension with the colleagues, even better.

Comment: I find that refusing to implement a manager's decision is a quick route to getting fired or relegated to menial tasks.

Comment: @toshiomagic it is not orders from a manager but a team - different horses different courses... And team discussions are not always orders...

Answer (score 3):

> If you can’t explain it simply, you don’t understand it well enough.
>
> ~ Albert Einstein

You need to be able to explain your work in a way that makes sense to someone with no knowledge of your field. The more complicated your work gets the better you have to get at explaining. When you learn to explain your work you mostly get to know your field even better. It's one thing to be able to write good code but it takes a lot more knowledge to explain *why* your code is good, and it takes even more to explain that to someone who might not know a thing about programming. **Practice your explaining skills.**

In my experience most situations like the ones you are describing arise from you knowing a lot, or thinking you do (no offense, but it happens to me a lot), and not being able to explain it in a way that others grasp it. This leads to others being hesitant to follow your lead and you getting frustrated with them for not grasping the stupidity of their ideas (especially if they come from one Google search). Again, the hard way's the best way and that's to practice your explaining skills. Learn to draw on examples that they understand, use metaphors, do what it takes to make them understand you. In the end they might still not listen to you but it's a skill that will help you immensely in just about every area of your life.

Comment: There is a reverse also: `“There are no simple answers to complex problems.” - Valerio Massimo Manfredi` That is, not everything can be explained "simple" to anybody - not when having to actually do some serious technical job. Explaining black holes to a grandmother using metaphors is one thing. Using metaphors when designing an airport's air traffic management systems - is another thing. If the engineers there understand ONLY metaphors but not engineering, they should actually go search for another job.

Comment: And another, also from Einstein: `“Everything should be made as simple as possible, but no simpler.”` Some things are complicated, and they should remain complicated. Simplifying them more, leads to undesirable results.

Comment: @virolino I agree that there are things that are complicated and will remain complicated. Solutions 'or answers' can't be kept simple but the explanation of that solution can be made at least so simple so that it's understandable. I am not suggesting simple solutions, just simple explanations.

Comment: I understood your intent, both in the answer and in the comment. But your quote greatly oversimplified things, no matter how you look at it. And it can be hurtful for somebody who does not know how to read your answer.

Comment: I am not so sure. Your first quote refers to solutions and has nothing to do with explanations. An answer is not the same as an explanation and an infinitely complex answer (or solution) can have a very simple explanation. The second one is, again, not directly referring to explanations. It's also not a very clear quote because what is the difference between simple and 'too simple'? It leaves a lot of room for arguments. I appreciate your last comment and edited my answer to make it sound less like 'this is the only way'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to back up your suggestions and your solutions with scientific arguments and proofs, design thinking methodology. Don't through singular solutions share your opinion with structured procedures

Comment: What do you mean by this phrase, *"Don't through singular solutions share your opinion with structured procedures"*? It doesn't quite make sense

Comment: Suggesting a solution in one phrase does is not be convincing or powerful, better to make a detailed presentation of all the arguments or behind the solution as well as the emplementation of its procedure.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I would like to suggest here.

- Keep an open mind. Often people get lost in minute details and makes mistakes, that are basic.
- If you are challenging someone else's solution, then be ready to be challenged back. Many times explaining things to someone, sharpens the idea.
- Concealed talent brings no reputation. If you want to be accepted as an expert, reflect your knowledge, in your work.
- Take part and offer suggestions in these "discussions" only if they are genuine and productive and if not, walk away.